# replace range by mean in a string

Tags: r, regex, data.table, gsub, stringr

I want to replace all number range by their mean. For example:

```
DT <- data.table(raw.data = c("1-2 min", "3-5 min or 2-4 min"),
desirable.data = c("1.5 min", "4 min or 3 min"))
```

Now, I can do this by

```
gsubfn(pattern = "(\\d+)(-)(\\d+)", ~ mean(c(as.numeric(..1), as.numeric(..3))), x = DT$raw.data)
```

Still, I'm wondering if there is a better solution. Because this approach returned an error "Variable '1' is not found in calling scope." when used in data.table, thanks!

More generally speaking, when I tried to replace certain part of the string by regex, I wanted to replace the "match" part according to the "group", rather than just some known string. But it seemed that functions like str_replace_all doesn't work this way. The argument "replacement" only allow some string as input.

Update

```
DT[, new := gsubfn(pattern = "(\\d+)(-)(\\d+)", 
                   ~ mean(c(as.numeric(..1), as.numeric(..3))), 
                   x = raw.data)]
```

When trying to use gsubfn in data.table, there's an error:

Error in `[.data.table(DT, , :=(new, gsubfn(pattern = "(\\d+)(-)(\\d+)",`  :
Variable '1' is not found in calling scope. Looking in calling scope because this symbol was prefixed with .. in the `j= parameter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the question does not give any error so we assume that the code being referred to is the code in the Note at the end, shown in reproducible form.

### ..1 and data.table

In data.table a variable whose name starts with .. is regarded to be an external variable whose name is the same but without the `..` so `..1` means the external variable `1`.  It seems that data.table understands that `...` is special in R and works correctly with it but it does not seem to know about `..1`, `..2`, etc.

Thus one cannot use `..1`, `..2`, etc. with data.table.  For example, here is a data.table example that does not involve gsubfn and we get the error found in the question.

```
library(data.table)

BODdt <- data.table(BOD)
BODdt[, X := sapply(demand, function(...) sqrt(..1))]
## Error in `[.data.table`(BODdt, , `:=`(X, sapply(demand, function(...) sqrt(..1)))) : 
##   Variable '1' is not found in calling scope. Looking in calling scope because this symbol was prefixed with .. in the j= parameter.
```

If we use dot dot dot instead of `..1` then there is no error.

```
BODdt <- data.table(BOD)
BODdt[, X := sapply(demand, function(...) sqrt(...))]
```

### gsubfn

The solution is simply not to use `..1` and `..2` or else use them but define the function externally to data.table.  There are many other ways to express this.  A few are shown below.  The dot dot dot refers to all the arguments.  x and y (or any variables not defined in the body) refer to the arguments in the order encountered in the body.  We have removed the parentheses around minus since that character string is not used in the function.

```
DT[, d := gsubfn("(\\d+)-(\\d+)", ~ mean(as.numeric(c(...))), raw.data)]

DT[, d := gsubfn("(\\d+)-(\\d+)", ~ mean(as.numeric(c(x, y))), raw.data)]

Mean <- function(...) mean(as.numeric(c(..1, ..2)))
DT[, d := gsubfn("(\\d+)-(\\d+)", Mean, raw.data)]

DT$d <- gsubfn("(\\d+)-(\\d+)", ~ mean(as.numeric(c(..1, ..2))), DT$raw.data)
```

### Note

Assumed code in reproducible form.

```
library(data.table)
library(gsubfn)

DT <- data.table(raw.data = c("1-2 min", "3-5 min or 2-4 min"),
desirable.data = c("1.5 min", "4 min or 3 min"))

DT[, d := gsubfn(pattern = "(\\d+)(-)(\\d+)", 
         ~ mean(c(as.numeric(..1), as.numeric(..3))), raw.data)]
```

Comment: IF no LHS is given then it will use dot dot dot if that appears in the body or use any free variables, i.e. variables that are referenced but not defined in the function,  in the order encountered.  It can also use ..1 and ..2, etc. but it seems there is some conflict with data.table in that case but not in the other cases.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the detailed explanation. (Sorry I deleted my previous comment because after reading your latest update, I thought my question had been answered

Comment: In your answer, you mentioned "in the order encountered in the body", I don't quite understand what does "body" refer to in this context.

Comment: The body of an ordinary R function is the code in the function, i.e. everything after the arguments. If `f` is any R function then `body(f)` shows its body.  Regarding the formula notation used in `gsubfn`, the RHS of the formula is used as the function body.  You might want to review `?as.function.formula` in gsubfn.

Comment: I have played around with this a bit more and found an example, now in the answer, that shows that the problem with ..1 is a general problem with data.table and has nothing to do with gsubfn.

Answer (score 3):

You can build string representations of R expressions and evaluate them using `str2expression` and `eval`.

```r
# replace ranges with calls to mean() and some quotes for string building
expr.str <- gsub("(\\d+)-(\\d+)", "', mean(c(\\1, \\2)), '", DT$raw.data)
# remove the extra ", " at the beginning
expr.str <- sub("^', ", "", expr.str)
# wrap in paste0() while adding the final single quote
expr.str <- paste0("paste0(", expr.str, "')")
# [1] "paste0(mean(c(1, 2)), ' min')"                           
# [2] "paste0(mean(c(3, 5)), ' min or ', mean(c(2, 4)), ' min')"

# create expressions and evaluate them
DT$data.mean <- sapply(str2expression(expr.str), eval)
#              raw.data      data.mean
# 1:            1-2 min        1.5 min
# 2: 3-5 min or 2-4 min 4 min or 3 min
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked as I expected. Comparing to the *gsubfn* method, your code also worked in data.table function without the "calling scope" error. Is it because of the eval function in the sapply?

Comment: I am not sure what caused the error you encountered. Actually, I just tried to run your code now (I was too lazy to install the `gsubfn` package beforehand) and it works just fine (with no error) for me.

Comment: Hi, I've edited my question to describe the error.

Answer (score 1):

What seems like a petty task is in fact a highly complex one (at least the way I see it; perhaps others can simplify this approach or come up with a simpler one in the first place). The problem is posed by the "or" value (if that were'nt there, things would be pretty easy). Therefore I propose a **two-step procedure**: first deal with the rows containing "or", then put the results back into the original data frame and deal with the rest:

```
DT %>%
  ### STEP 1: 
  #   separate out the row(s) with "or":
  filter(str_detect(raw.data, "or")) %>%
  # give each range a separate row:
  separate_rows(raw.data, sep = " or ") %>%
  mutate(
    # extract digits, convert to numeric, and calculate mean:
    Mean = lapply(lapply(str_extract_all(raw.data, "\\d+"), as.numeric), mean)) %>%
  # unnest list:
  unnest(Mean) %>%
  # paste separated elements back together:
  summarise(
    raw.data = str_c(raw.data, collapse = " "),
    Mean = str_c(Mean, collapse = " ")) %>%
  mutate(
    # add "min":
    Mean = gsub("(\\d+)\\s(\\d+)","\\1 min or \\2 min", Mean)) %>%
  ### STEP 2: 
  #   bind result back together with DT extecpt for wos with "or" value:
  bind_rows(DT %>% filter(!str_detect(raw.data, "or")), .) %>%
  mutate(
    # if `mean` is NA, repeat procedure for mean calculation from above:
    Mean = ifelse(is.na(Mean), 
                 lapply(lapply(str_extract_all(raw.data, "\\d+"), as.numeric), mean),
                 Mean),
    # add "min"
    Mean = sub("(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)$", "\\1 min", Mean)) 

         raw.data            Mean
1:         1-2 min        1.5 min
2: 3-5 min 2-4 min 4 min or 3 min
```